# WINAPI / c++: Moving borderless window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a borderless window using these styles: `WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_OVERLAPPED`

The problem is that the window can't be moved. I know that I could do something like getting mouse click position, and then calculate where the window would end up everytime there comes a `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

But this solution is not stable, because when I move my mouse too fast, it gets out of the window, and then it won't react. I dont want to set up a hook, because they are too slow. I have searched the internet, but nothing came up at all.

What I ideally want to, is to create a window, that is able to be moved without borders or captions, where I don't need to track the mouse myself, but where Windows does it for me, like making the whole window a caption.

Comment: Why does the form need to be responsive to you intentionally moving it fast?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Because that's how people expect windows to behave.  If you started dragging a window, the window should end up where your drag ends, not at some point in-between where the mouse cursor happened to outrace the window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement dragging a window using its client area?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773771/how-do-i-implement-dragging-a-window-using-its-client-area)

Comment: @HansPassant: Maybe, didn't see that. But anyway, thanks for answering, jamesdlin.

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178030/cbuilder-create-a-tform-with-borderstyle-bsnone-that-is-nevertheless-movable

Comment: sendMessage(myWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, 61458, 0) ; Do this on mousedown event. It is the window system move command. You can now drag the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that I could do something like getting mouse click position, and then calculate where the window would end up everytime there comes a `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. But this solution is not stable, because when I move my mouse too fast, it gets out of the window, and then it won't react.

You can fix that by calling [`SetCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262.aspx) when you receive the mouse click.  You then will continue to receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE` even after the mouse cursor leaves your window.  When the user is finished dragging and release the mouse cursor, you then should call [`ReleaseCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646261.aspx).

> What I ideally want to, is to create a window, that is able to be moved without borders or captions, where I don't need to track the mouse myself, but where Windows does it for me, like making the whole window a caption.

If you really want to do that, you could respond to the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618.aspx) message and return `HTCAPTION`.

Comment: If the entire window should be draggable, the second option is the winner. This is the standard way of solving the problem of dragging borderless windows, and you'll find suggestions/solutions all over the web. Do make sure that you also handle `WM_SETCURSOR` to provide the correct visual hinting at your window's draggability.

Comment: Thank you, the second solution is perfect - just what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh, and I would like to give you +1, but I do not have enough reputation, as this is my first question. :(

Comment: @CodyGray And if you don't want the entire window to be draggable, the `WM_NCHITTEST` handler just needs to be more selective about when it returns `HTCAPTION`.

Comment: @jamesdin - btw, my old htspy introduces the topic visually and in detail: http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/htspy.zip

Answer (score 3):

try `PostMessage(hwnd,WM_SYSCOMMAND,SC_SIZE+9,0)` on `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.

Comment: What is `SC_SIZE+9` supposed to be?  Do you mean `SC_MOVE`?

Comment: SC_SIZE+9 = SC_DRAG, undocumented, just try it :-)

Comment: -1 for recommending undocumented features that violate the programmer's contract, *especially* when there's a better, documented way of solving the problem

Comment: Even though it's undocumented, +1 for a 1-liner solution that expresses the intent exactly (the solution `NCHITTEST` -> `HTCAPTION` is a lie, and who knows how clicking the caption will act in the future?).

Comment: This is the best solution. It's not our fault that Microsoft forgot to document this command.

Comment: @rustyx Clicking captions is a standard way of moving windows.  There is no reason to change it, it's an *established* way to accomplish to task, and Microsoft goes to great lengths to avoid breaking compatibility.  I disagree with "that expresses the intent exactly"; IMO this 1-liner is much more cryptic.